# SVG parent animates but not the child SVG

Tags: svg, css-animations, css-transforms

Why does the parent SVG rotate but not the child SVG?

Note the parent element of the first SVG will animate, but not the child element of the second SVG

Tried in Chrome and IE 11 (yes, `.parent-svg-1` rotates in IE 11), both browsers had same results.
Also tried in FireFox: `.child-svg-2` rotates but not from its center.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {

    let wd = 720 - 90
    let min = wd - 32.5
    let max = wd + 32.5
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)

    // Note the parent element of the first SVG will animate,
    // but not the child element of the second SVG
    $('.parent-svg-1, .child-svg-2')
      .stop()
      .animate({
        rotate: num
      }, {
        step: function(now, fx) {
          $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)')
        },
        duration: 500
      }, 'linear')
  }, 500)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg class="parent-svg-1" viewBox="0 0 60 60" width="50" height="50">
 <svg class="child-svg-1">
  <path d="M 10 30 L 20 20 L 20 25 L 50 25 L 50 35 L 20 35 L 20 40 Z" fill="#55f" />
 </svg>
</svg>

<svg class="parent-svg-2" viewBox="0 0 60 60" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="110">
 <svg class="child-svg-2">
  <path d="M 10 30 L 20 20 L 20 25 L 50 25 L 50 35 L 20 35 L 20 40 Z" fill="#f00" />
 </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: They both rotate for me on Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

In SVG 1.1, the `transform` attribute is not supported for `<svg>` elements.  It works in the first case because the SVG is embedded in HTML and the transform is being handled by the HTML layout engine.  Not the SVG rendering code.

Under SVG2, which browsers are still in the process of implementing, `transform` **is** allowed. It appears that Firefox has implemented that, but Chrome hasn't.

One simple fix is to change the child `<svg>` element to a `<g>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {

    let wd = 720 - 90
    let min = wd - 32.5
    let max = wd + 32.5
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)

    // Note the parent element of the first SVG will animate,
    // but not the child element of the second SVG
    $('.parent-svg-1, .child-svg-2')
      .stop()
      .animate({
        rotate: num
      }, {
        step: function(now, fx) {
          $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)')
        },
        duration: 500
      }, 'linear')
  }, 500)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg class="parent-svg-1" viewBox="0 0 60 60" width="50" height="50">
 <svg class="child-svg-1">
  <path d="M 10 30 L 20 20 L 20 25 L 50 25 L 50 35 L 20 35 L 20 40 Z" fill="#55f" />
 </svg>
</svg>

<svg class="parent-svg-2" viewBox="0 0 60 60" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="110">
 <g class="child-svg-2">
  <path d="M 10 30 L 20 20 L 20 25 L 50 25 L 50 35 L 20 35 L 20 40 Z" fill="#f00" />
 </g>
</svg>
```